# Asp.net core rc2, I am able to authenticate with external login but i am redirected to this

Tags: asp.net-core

```
https://localhost:44310/signin-facebook?code={someCode}
```

This is a problem for both LinkedIn and Facebook. Here is some of the server code:

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookOptions
                                  { 
                                      AppId = "", 
                                      AppSecret = "", 
                                      Scope = {"email"}, 
                                      Fields = {"name", "email"}, 
                                  }); 

app.UseLinkedInAuthentication(new LinkedInAuthenticationOptions‌​
                                  { 
                                     ClientId = "",
                                     ClientSecret ="", 
                                  });
```

Comment: can you show some of your code?

Comment: app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookOptions()
            {
                AppId = "",
                AppSecret = "",
                Scope = {"email"},
                Fields = {"name", "email"},
                

                
                
                
            });

 app.UseLinkedInAuthentication(new AspNet.Security.OAuth.LinkedIn.LinkedInAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                ClientId = "",
                ClientSecret ="",
               
               

            });

Comment: Everything seems ok but only the problem is it doenst redirects to /Account/ExternalLoginCallback

Comment: Moved code sample from comment to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> app.UseIdentity();

// My bad it was clearly mentioned to use external provider between these two

> app.UseMvc();